# Operate a variable from 'any' iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a bit more readable logging messages for my program.
For this purpose I'm searching a way to implement sort of advanced '***any***' iterator.

It should either way return index of satisfying data index or iterated cell itself
instead of just returning True/False on satisfied condition.

Here is a possible pseudo-code for explanation:

```
messages = [(0, None),(1, None), (2, "data")]

if any(data is not None for id, data in messages):
    print(f"Tuple with data has id: {id} and data: '{data}'.") 
else:
    print(f"There is no message with filled data")

# should output: "Tuple with data has id: 2 and data: 'data'."
```

I've tried several ways like using walrus operator, using ***global*** operator, print inside ***if*** operator or even implementing my own iterator
(but this topic is new for me so probably it still can be a solution)

I would like to avoid any extra ***for*** cycle for better optimization, readability and also for mastering python.

Thank you for any ideas in advance!

Comment: A `for` loop is exactly how you should solve this problem.  Loop through the list, print the message and do a `break` if you find the desired item, use the optional `else` clause of the loop to print the "not found" message.

Comment: Beside the point, but `global` and `if` are statements, not operators.

Comment: Related: [Get the first item from an iterable that matches a condition](/q/2361426/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop and break out when the matching element is found. If you don't break out, print the message saying nothing was found.

```
for id, data in messages:
    if data is not None:
        print(f"Tuple with data has id: {id} and data: '{data}'.")
        break
else:
    print(f"There is no message with filled data")
```

Comment: Personally, I like to put `else:  # No break` as a reminder of what it does. Sometimes I forget and I think it means "if the loop is never entered, (i.e the iterable is empty), do this".

Answer (score 1):

If you really want something similar to what you've already written, you can use `next()` on a filtering generator expression and catch `StopIteration`. But personally, I think it's clearer to use a plain for-loop like [Barmar suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75140481/4518341).

```
try:
    id_, data = next((id_, data) for id_, data in messages if data is not None)
except StopIteration:
    print("There is no message with filled data")
else:
    print(f"Tuple with data has id: {id_} and data: '{data}'.")
```

(Here I'm also avoiding [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `id` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).)